# Typewriter effect in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am a very novice java learner,
I am trying to ADD typewriter effect to my app in android studio. I have defined the class "typeWriter" for the effect, still I have problem to use it in my app. specifically, to use the text from other classes.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_screen);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IntroImage);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HelpAndDefine);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    button1.setTransformationMethod(null);
    button2.setTransformationMethod(null);
    button3.setTransformationMethod(null);
    typeWriter txtView = findViewById(R.id.HelpAndDefine);
    txtView.setText("");
    txtView.setCharacterDelays(150);
    txtView.animateText("");


    story.startingPoint();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `quick and dirty` implementation to give you an idea. You will need to build a `better logic` based on your requirements. The idea here is to use a `Handler` to append the characters of the `word` (which is `Hello` in below example) with a certain `delay` to give it a `typewriter` kind of effect.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      
    TextView typingt;
    Button typingb;
  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          
        typingb = findViewById(R.id.typingb);
        typingt = findViewById(R.id.typingt);
          
        typingb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        typingt.setText("H");
                    }
                }, 300);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        typingt.append("e");
                    }
                }, 400);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        typingt.append("e");
                    }
                }, 500);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        typingt.append("l");
                    }
                }, 600);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        typingt.append("o");
                    }
                }, 700);
                
              }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/typingt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/typingb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Typing Animation" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```